# How to display CLOB (or BLOB) String in iReport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, blob, ireport, clob

I need to display a CLOB field with longer than 4000 characters in a text field using in iReport. I am using iReport version 5.5.0, I tried converting the CLOB to InputStream but it did not work, all I get is:

```
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@43842a66
```

I tried getSubString(long,int) but it only works for strings smaller than 4000 chars. stringValue() and toString() also did not work.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

Clob.getSubString(long,int) method worked fine in my latter tests, I don't know why it didn't work before. So I used:

```
$F{FIELD}.getSubString( (long)1, (int)$F{FIELD}.length() )
```

eventually. It may not be the best option, but I figured max length of a String (2147483647) is more than enough for the field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, and i found the following solutions.

**First**

one is placing the following statement in the `Textfield` expression. catch to this is the field should be free of carriage returns and line feeds to show the complete field value. I populate the field through `sql` query.

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader($F{FIELD_NAME})).readLine()
```

**Second**

creating a method in a class where in the `InputStream` is converted to `ByteArrayOutputStream` and converting it to `String` and then calling this method in the `Textfield` expression with `CLOB` value passed in.

In both cases the field should be declared as `java.io.InputStream`.

For more [details](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/507517/handling-oracle-clobs).

Answer (score 0):

After looking everywhere, finally, I have found out how to fix this issue.
Simply If you are using Ireport Designer Go to `Report Inspector section -> Fields -> click` the field to be modified from Properties change Filed Class to `java.lang.String`